# Menus too far apart on Xfce

Tags: xfce, gtk3

I have noticed on several gtk applications, that the menu spacing is too far apart. I'm using Xfce, greybird theme. But this seems to happen no matter which theme i use.

On the attached image, you can see what I mean. Sometimes there are large tabs, I'm guessing this is a gtk/gnome 3 "feature", I prefer tighter menus etc.

Anyone got any suggestions how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What programs is this occurring on? Do you have Xubuntu or is Xfce an additional desktop environment?

Comment: I happens on a few applications. Most noticeably on Transmission-gtk, bluefish, Nemo.

Answer (score 0):

I believe many years later it was the theme that was at fault for causing this issue.